# Deriving an equation

Tags: probability

How do we derive the following: $$ -\sum_{x} \sum_{y}  p(x,y) \left( \log_{2} p(x) + \log_{2} p(y) - \log_{2} p(x,y) \right)$$ $$= -\sum_{y} p(y) \log_{2} p(y)+\sum_{x} p(x) \sum_{y} p(y|x) \log_{2} p(y|x)$$

The first equation simplified is: $$-\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(x)-\sum_{x}\sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(x,y)+\sum_{x}\sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(x,y)$$

Do we just use the fact that $p(x,y) = p(y)p(x|y) = p(x)p(y|x)$ and substitute in?

Comment: What do you get after doing the substitution?

Answer (score -1):

This is just a guess: We know that $$-\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(y) = -\sum_{y} \sum_{x} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(y)$$

$$= -\sum_{y} p(y) \log_{2} p(y)$$

Also $$\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2}p(x,y)- \sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(x)$$
 $$ = \sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log_{2} \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}$$

$$ = \sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(y|x) p(x) \log_{2} p(y|x)$$

$$= \sum_{x} p(x) \sum_{y} p(y|x) \log_{2} p(y|x)$$

Thus $$ -\sum_{x} \sum_{y}  p(x,y) \left( \log_{2} p(x) + \log_{2} p(y) - \log_{2} p(x,y) \right)$$ $$= -\sum_{y} p(y) \log_{2} p(y)+\sum_{x} p(x) \sum_{y} p(y|x) \log_{2} p(y|x)$$

Comment: The first thing that *We know* in your post seems wrong.

Comment: @Did: What is wrong about it?

Comment: Try some concrete cases. You seem to have confused $\log p(x,y)$ with $\log p(y)$.

Comment: @Did: I was using the fact that $\sum_{x} p(x,y) = p(y)$. Then $\sum_{x} p(x,y) \log_{2} p(x,y) = p(y) \log_{2} p(y)$.

Comment: No. As I already indicated, this would be true if one had $\log p(y)$ instead of $\log p(x,y)$ in the summation over $(x,y)$.

Comment: @Did: So it seems the equation is not true?

Comment: The identity to prove **IS** true.

Comment: @Did: Would you say the second part is correct?

Comment: Well... except when you replace $\log-\log$ by $\log/\log$.

Comment: @Did: I used the identity $\log_{b} (x) - \log_{b}(y) = \log_{b} \frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: @Did: I have corrected the first part.

Comment: @Did: I am correct. I think I just copied the question incorrectly which was incorrect by the original post. "The first equation simplified" was wrong.